# Using Polymorphic Function to Split (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

How to do this using polymorphic function? I'm a new learner, Thanks!
split :: [(a,b)] -> ([a,b]), example split [(1,'a') , (2, 'b')] = ([1,2], "ab")

Comment: Dear Wei Yan. Please refer to this information (http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) and reform your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [`unzip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:unzip) from the [`Prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html) module which is imported by default:

```hs
unzip :: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])

  unzip [(1,'a'),(2,'b')]
= ([1,2],"ab")
```

**Pro Tip:** When you want to find a certain function in Haskell you can use the [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) search engine.